# start a new process in java,invoke an exe, but can find the .txt file this exe output in nowhere

Tags: java, subprocess, output

I invoke this exe command in prompt line, it works fine, just output the txt file to the path I told it.
But I cannot find this file when I invoke this exe from java

the function I use is

```
Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

any clue will be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set its working directory(where the directory which contains the file you want to execute).
Do do this:

```
Process p;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("your command", "arg", "arg", "etc");
pb.directory("/thepath/to/thefile");
p = pb.start();
```